# Plotting constant from a file in GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file containing a gaussian function, and an other date file that contains one column with 3 rows. Those three row are all constant which are

1: mean+variance

2: mean

3: mean-variance

from the gaussian in the first file.

I would like to plot all these as constant lines on the gaussian function. I've tried the "every" command, (plot "stat.dat" every ::0::0 w lines) which didn't work.

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "gauss.png"

set samples 1000                                
x0 = -5
s2 = 1

set xrange [-10:10] 
set yrange [0:0.5]

plot (1/sqrt(2*pi*s2))*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*s2))  title "Gaussian",        \
     "stat.dat" u 1:(5) every ::0::0 w impulse title "mean + variance", \
     "stat.dat" u 1:(5) every ::1::1 w impulse title "mean",            \
     "stat.dat" u 1:(5) every ::2::2 w impulse title "mean - variance"
```

I have replaced your data file which contains the gaussian function by an analytical expression. The result looks as follows:

[image: gaussian with constants]

Comment: Yes ! :D that looks a whole lot to what I wanted to do ! Thank you kind sir. Now to push my luck ... would you be able to have something that looks like this ? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/gaufcn2.html